# Transition matrix for Jordan canonical form

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form, generalized-eigenvector

I have this matrix:

$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 3 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &  3 
\end{bmatrix}$$

The characteristic polynomial is $(3-\lambda)^3,$ so the eigenvalue is $\lambda=3$ alone.

$$(A-\lambda I) = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &  0 
\end{bmatrix}\implies \textrm{the eigenvalue is } v=(1,0,0)\textrm{ alone.}$$

So, I have the Jordan canonical form:

$$J = \begin{bmatrix}
3 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 3 & 1 \\
0 & 0 &  3 
\end{bmatrix}.$$

Now, I want to find the transition matrix $P$ such that $A=PJP^{-1}.$

I know that I need to find the generalized eigenvector, but I don't know what to do with them.

I saw that 
$$(A-\lambda I)^{2} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 &  0 
\end{bmatrix}$$

So, can I take as the generalized eigenvector the vector $w=(0,1,0)$? Since $\ker((A-\lambda)^{2})=\textrm{Span}\{v,(0,1,0)\}$, I think that is fine.

Now, 
$$(A-\lambda I)^{3} = \begin{bmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 &  0 
\end{bmatrix},$$
so, the generalized eigenspace is $\Bbb{R}^{3}.$ Can I take as the final generalized eigenvector the vector $u=(0,0,1)$?

And now, how can I construct the matrix P?

I think there is something wrong, since the basis that I found is just the canonical basis, and in this basis the matrix $A$ is not in Jordan form.

Comment: choose $v_3$ so that $(A-3I) v_3=w$

Comment: You've got the wrong kernel for $(A-3I)^2$. It's $\mathrm{span}\{(0,0,1)\}$, not $\mathrm{span}\{(0,1,0)\}$.

Comment: And you got $(A-3I)^2$ wrong, too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basis you find, in the end, will have the form $\beta=[\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3]$, where:

1. $(A-3I)\mathbf{v}_3 = \mathbf{v}_2$;
2. $(A-3I)\mathbf{v}_2 = \mathbf{v}_1$;
3. $(A-3I)\mathbf{v}_1 = \mathbf{0}$.

So you need to find a vector, $\mathbf{v}_3$, which is (i) in the nullspace of $(A-3I)^3$; **but** (ii) **not** in the nullspace of $(A-3I)^2$.

Here, *everything* is in the nullspace of $(A-3I)^3$, since $(A-3I)^3$ is the zero matrix.

You've compute $(A-3I)^2$ incorrectly: the correct calculation gives
$$(A-3I)^2 = \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right) \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 1 & 2\\
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0\end{array}\right) = \left(\begin{array}{rrr}
0 & 0 & -1\\
0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right).$$
The nullspace is $\{ (x,y,z) \mid z=0\}$ (note your calculation is wrong, even for the matrix you got; you don't need $y=0$, you need $z=0$). So all you need to do is take any vector that is *not* in that nullspace. In particular, you *cannot* take $(0,1,0)$ (which *is* in the nullspace of $(A-3I)^2$); but you *can* take $(0,0,1)$, which is not.

If you pick $\mathbf{v}_3=(0,0,1)$, then $\mathbf{v}_2 = (A-3I)\mathbf{v}_3 = (2,-1,0)$; and $\mathbf{v}_1 = (A-3I)\mathbf{v}_2 = (-1,0,0)$.

Comment: Thank you!
So, the matrix P columns are the vectors $v_1,v_2,v_3$?

Comment: If you want $A=PJP^{-1}$, yes; the matrix with columns given by $\mathbf{v}_1,\mathbf{v}_2,\mathbf{v}_3$, in that order, is the transition matrix from $\beta$ to the standard matrix. $A$ "hears" standard vectors and "speaks" standard vectors; $J$ hears and speaks $\beta$-vectors. So you want $P^{-1}$ to translate standard-to-$\beta$ and $P$ to translate $\beta$-to-standard.